# Heroku showing error Method Not Allowed when Flask App deployed

Tags: python, html, css, flask, heroku

When I deployed my flask app on heroku it showed error Method not allowed. When I check my log file it is showing OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use.

```
2020-07-07T07:28:34.934435+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:835: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.

2020-07-07T07:28:34.934438+00:00 app[web.1]:   'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
2020-07-07T07:28:34.944563+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
2020-07-07T07:28:34.944611+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Environment: production
2020-07-07T07:28:34.944688+00:00 app[web.1]:    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.

2020-07-07T07:28:34.944744+00:00 app[web.1]:    Use a production WSGI server instead.
2020-07-07T07:28:34.944802+00:00 app[web.1]:  * Debug mode: on
2020-07-07T07:28:34.954182+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-07 07:28:34 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-07-07T07:28:34.954183+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

2020-07-07T07:28:34.954184+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker

2020-07-07T07:28:34.954185+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2020-07-07T07:28:34.954185+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-07-07T07:28:34.954186+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()

2020-07-07T07:28:34.954186+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1030, in run_simple
2020-07-07T07:28:34.954196+00:00 app[web.1]:     s.bind(server_address)

2020-07-07T07:28:34.954203+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

2020-07-07T07:28:34.954593+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-07 07:28:34 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)

2020-07-07T07:07:34.321162+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-07 07:07:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)

2020-07-07T07:07:34.415124+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-07 07:07:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master

2020-07-07T07:07:34.415277+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-07-07 07:07:34 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

2020-07-07T07:07:34.505898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3

2020-07-07T07:07:34.857697+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: kill the process running at that end point or change the end point and deploy again

Comment: can you please tell me a little bit more as I am new to Flask and deploying it first time on heroku

Comment: just change your port address